# Overriding Error in iNET framework in OMNET++

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

I'm receiving error "Overriding error" even though all libraries avilable at the workspace. Below are the relevant code snippets with mentioned errors:

```
#include "inet/common/INETDefs.h"
namespace inet {
#if OMNETPP_VERSION >= 0x0405
class INET_API InetPacketBytesPrinter : public cMessagePrinter
{
protected:
mutable bool showEncapsulatedPackets;  
public:
InetPacketBytesPrinter() { showEncapsulatedPackets = true; }
virtual ~InetPacketBytesPrinter() {}
virtual int getScoreFor(cMessage *msg) const override;
virtual void printMessage(std::ostream& os, cMessage *msg) const override;
};
```

**Error:** ‘virtual void inet::InetPacketBytesPrinter::printMessage(std::ostream&, omnetpp::cMessage*) const’ marked ‘override’, but does not override

```
Register_MessagePrinter(InetPacketBytesPrinter);
```

**Error:** invalid new-expression of abstract class type ‘inet::InetPacketBytesPrinter’

```
static const char INFO_SEPAR[] = "  \t";
int InetPacketBytesPrinter::getScoreFor(cMessage *msg) const{
return msg->isPacket() ? 18 : 0;
}
void InetPacketBytesPrinter::printMessage(std::ostream& os, cMessage *msg) const
{
std::string outs;
showEncapsulatedPackets = true;
for (cPacket *pk = dynamic_cast<cPacket *>(msg); showEncapsulatedPackets && pk; pk = pk->getEncapsulatedPacket()) {    
    std::ostringstream out;
    out << pk->getClassName() << ":" << pk->getByteLength() << " bytes";
    if (outs.length())
        out << INFO_SEPAR << outs;
    outs = out.str();
}
os << outs;
}
#endif
}
```

**Console:**
12:46:31 **** Incremental Build of configuration gcc-release for project ansainet ****
make MODE=release all
cd src && make all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/abbuser/Subhash/omnetpp-5.6.1/samples/ansainet/src'
inet/common/packet/InetPacketBytesPrinter.cc
inet/common/packet/InetPacketBytesPrinter.cc:33:18: error: ‘virtual void inet::InetPacketBytesPrinter::printMessage(std::ostream&, omnetpp::cMessage*) const’ marked ‘override’, but does not override
virtual void printMessage(std::ostream& os, cMessage *msg) const override;
^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/abbuser/Subhash/omnetpp-5.6.1/include/omnetpp/globals.h:21:0,
from /home/abbuser/Subhash/omnetpp-5.6.1/include/omnetpp/cobjectfactory.h:20,
from /home/abbuser/Subhash/omnetpp-5.6.1/include/omnetpp.h:30,
from ./inet/common/INETDefs.h:28,
from inet/common/packet/InetPacketBytesPrinter.cc:18:
inet/common/packet/InetPacketBytesPrinter.cc: In function ‘void inet::{anonymous}::__onstartup_func_36()’:
inet/common/packet/InetPacketBytesPrinter.cc:36:1: error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type ‘inet::InetPacketBytesPrinter’
Register_MessagePrinter(InetPacketBytesPrinter);
^
inet/common/packet/InetPacketBytesPrinter.cc:24:16: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘inet::InetPacketBytesPrinter’:
class INET_API InetPacketBytesPrinter : public cMessagePrinter
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/abbuser/Subhash/omnetpp-5.6.1/include/omnetpp.h:68:0,
from ./inet/common/INETDefs.h:28,
from inet/common/packet/InetPacketBytesPrinter.cc:18:
/home/abbuser/Subhash/omnetpp-5.6.1/include/omnetpp/cmessageprinter.h:110:22: note:     virtual void omnetpp::cMessagePrinter::printMessage(std::ostream&, omnetpp::cMessage*, const omnetpp::cMessagePrinter::Options*) const
virtual void printMessage(std::ostream& os, cMessage *msg, const Options *options) const = 0;
^~~~~~~~~~~~
Makefile:1127: recipe for target '../out/gcc-release/src/inet/common/packet/InetPacketBytesPrinter.o' failed
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/abbuser/Subhash/omnetpp-5.6.1/samples/ansainet/src'
make[1]: *** [../out/gcc-release/src/inet/common/packet/InetPacketBytesPrinter.o] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'all' failed
"make MODE=release all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

12:46:35 Build Failed. 6 errors, 0 warnings. (took 3s.328ms)

Answer (score 1):

The INET version you are trying to build is too old to be built with OMNeT++ 5.6. You should either use an older OMNeT++ version (that is indicated in the README file of the INET release), or use a newer version INET (probably the latest 3.6.x version?)

Comment: Thanks! @Rudi for your comment. I am working on LLDP (Link Layer Detection Protocol) and as per my understanding, the newer version of iNET doesn't have support for LLDP...(please correct if I am wrong)

Comment: AFAIK, no version of INET has an LLDP implementation, so in that regard, you can use any version of INET as a starting point.

Comment: So, are you aware of any framework based on OMNET++ which has some insights on LLDP?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [documentation](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/api/classomnetpp_1_1cMessagePrinter.html#a5c8ea218923d2933c3088fe617646acb) the `cMessagePrinter::printMessage` method takes three parameters, but your version only has two, therefore it's not an override.

Change your `printMessage` signature to be the same as the method you are overriding.

Comment: Thank you @John! The mentioned errors have been addressed but these modifications created another bug in the following section:   **printMessage(os, packet->getEncapsulatedPacket());                                                                                                  
 ** with Error message: **inet/common/packet/InetPacketPrinter.cc:198:61: error: no matching function for call to ‘inet::InetPacketPrinter::printMessage(std::ostream&, omnetpp::cPacket*) const’**

Comment: @SubhashKumar The overall error that you are making is that the `printMessage` method requires three arguments, either when you override it or when you call it. You need to provide a third `Options` argument. I'm sorry but I'm not familar with this library so I can't advise on what that should be.